# How to return the highest count values in a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

I need to return the 3 highest counts in a dictionary that have a length of over 2 and I can't figure out how to approach it. This is what I tried:

```
def highest3(diction) :
list = []
for key, value in diction.items() :
    if len(key) > 2 :
        list.append((key, value))
dictionary = dict(list)
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: First of all you can't have a **sorted** dictionary in any ways,

Comment: BTW what is expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort the **keys** of the given dictionary based on their values in the given dictionary in the decreasing order and then slice the results upto 3 elements.

```
sample_dict = {'aid':1, 'alide':2, 'all':6, 'allies':2, 'allowed':1, 'almost':1, 'along':1, 'also':2, 'always':3}

for i in sorted(sample_dict.keys(), key = lambda x:sample_dict[x], reverse = True)[:3]:
    print i, sample_dict[i]

>>> all 6
    always 3
    allies 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the list and get the top 3 values.

```
def top3(counts) :
    listA = []
    for k, v in counts.items():
        if len(k) > 2:
            listA.append((k, v))
    listA.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
    listA = listA[:3]
    print(listA)
```

Answer (score 0):

First get a list of all items with key length greater than two:

```
>>> items = [item for item in counts.items() if len(item[0]) > 2]
```

Now sort them by descending values and ascending keys:

```
>>> items.sort(key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))
```

And finally, take the first three items:

```
>>> print(items[:3])
[('all', 6), ('always', 3), ('also', 2)]
```